# Prove $\cos(n_k x)$ does not converge pointwise on $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

There are strictly increasing sequence $n_1<n_2<\dots<n_k<\dots$ which are positive integers. I want to prove on the domain $[0,2\pi]$ where $\cos(n_kx)$ converges does not coincide with $[0,2\pi]$. I have proved in the first question that it converges on a measurable set. The hint is that "Relate pointwise convergence with convergence in $L^2$".

First I want to show my proof that does not concern the hint. For $x=2\pi r$ where $r$ is irrational, we have the conclusion that $\cos(nx)$ are not periodic. Although there might be $n_k$ where it converges for certain $x$, but given such a sequence it can not make the sequence on all such $x$ converges. It seems simple to think but lacks strong justifiction, any thought to fix this would be appreciated.

So I have another proof using the hint. I want to use dominated convergence theorem. Suppose $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $[0,2\pi]$, and since it has upper bound $g=1$, we can apply dominated convergence theorem $\int f_n=\int f=0$(I need a little more argument here, but the reason is that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f_n$ changes so fast that makes the integral all cancelled to $0$. And then I want to use DCT on $f^2$ and ${f_n}^2$ to raise a contradiction. My problem here is that: whether ${f_n}^2\to f^2$? And I can have $\int {\cos(n_k x)}^2=\int \frac{1-\cos(2n_kx)}{2}=1/2$ as $n_k\to \infty$, but what can I say about $\int f^2$?

At last, I want to say that I know there is a similar problem on this site which is prove where it converges has measure zero. But mine is simpler so I can use different techniques to prove it and here I just want some help with my own proof. I hope this would not be considered as duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what is $\|\cos(n x) - \cos(m x)\|_2^2$?